# When making websites for clients, what's the best way to handle payments that clients pay for, but you design?

Tags: web-development, freelancing, websites, payment

When making a website for a client, how do you deal with payments (hosting, theme, plugins, software, ect) when you are setting everything up for them, though the client will be paying for the systems/software?

In the past its just been friends and family who give me a CC, though not sure my client would be ok with that. I want to make this very easy for them, they are not tech-savvy and I do not want to have too many back and forths with them when creating the site. What do you normally do for clients? Do you send them a list of everything to pay for, and they give you codes (this seems messy), or do you put everything in your name, and change the payment once I hand over the site (this seems like it could cause issues)?

I'd love to hear thoughts on the easiest way to handle this.

Thank you so much, really appreciate it.

Answer (score -2):

Great that you are making progress into the area of Entrepreneurship. It is amazing when you get to this point of the game.
There are few approaches I would recommend.

You can bundle all of their expenses into one yearly invoice. 
Then you send the invoice manually via email to them prior to the year start. 
After payment, you turn their services on, and so every year you do that.

Or you can have small business site where you bring them to add credit card info and you use one of the payment providers out like [PayPal](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/) or [Stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions) to hook and renew automatically the payment.

Third option, is to send them individual invoices every time you got  ability for service they enjoy. That approach is something I would not recommend as it leads to issues over time and you cannot scale in your development.

Then, remember to send them reminder via email that bill is due and when payment is coming.

Also, after payment, make sure you send them manually or auto conformation for the payment and when next payment is is.

Also, watch out for clients that pay one time and them make excuses. 
Send them reminders few times and then ask them to pay or cancel their bills. Do that very quickly, right within 3-4 weeks period, but under a month. 
If you exceed more than a month and they have not payed you, you will not see any money from them in general.

Try to never store their credit cards on your end, ever. By using electronic invoices let the payment providers handle their CC.

Disclaimer: I founded [batch geocoder CSV2GEO](https://csv2geo.com)

Comment: Great suggestions, really helpful. I really appreciate you taking the time out of our busy lives to give this newbie some advice. You're the best!!